# Custom change of NumberFormat for (Dutch) locale

Tags: java, locale, currency-formatting

I have a problem. I work with amounts in application, and I need to localize the format. I use the `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` of java.util.Locale. By most cases it looks just fine. But the negative numbers are the problem. The predefined format for Dutch nl-NL locale looks like this

```
€ 200,00-
```

but according to the standards in the Netherlands, it should be

```
€ -200,00
```

The example is `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("nl", "NL")).format(-200)`. I don't want to change the format otherwise.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [this](http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2013/11/formatting-dutch-currency-amounts/) explains the problem pretty well (discrepancy between CLDR - used by Java - and official Dutch language recommendation).

To use a different format than the CLDR one you have to define it yourself, using the default format for positive values and a different one for negative numbers:

```
((DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("NL", "nl"))).applyPattern("¤ #,##0.00;¤ -#").format(-200);
```

(how you decompose this, where you apply the pattern etc will of course depend on your existing code)

`¤ #,##0.00` is the current default Dutch pattern for positive values, `¤ -#` is the new pattern for negative values which means "currency symbol first, then a non-breaking space (i.e. `\u00a0`, not the regular SPC character), then negative symbol, then same format as positive value" (`;` separates positive value format from negative one in the formatting string).